# jQuery setinterval function change css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, setinterval

I want to make a function to change my background `<header>` every 5 seconds.

On the one hand I have an image that changes every X time, It is generated by a php file:

```
../bg.php
```

So I've done that I change the background-image with `$("header").css()`.

Running the script like this:

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        var $container = $("header");
        $container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php)");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php)");
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But does not change by itself.

Comment: Maybe a cache issue... Maybe that's why it seems to not be refreshed... Try setting it like `$container.css("background-image", "url('bg.php?a="+Math.random()+"')");`

Comment: FYI you say that it refreshes every 5 seconds, but it is implemented to refresh every 9.

Comment: @LcSalazar is a valid solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because your browser cache it. place a random number at the end of url:

```
$container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php?rnd=" +  Math.random() + ")");
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php?rnd=" +  Math.random() + ")");
}, 9000);
```

Comment: This would work, but there is a really small, but still present chance that a number could be repeated and the cached image could be accessed...

Comment: set your http cache header to **no-cache** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess, but there's a good chance that the browser is just caching the file. You could add cache control headers on the server, or else add a nonce parameter each time you change the background:

```
    var counter = 1, refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php?_=" + counter++ + ")");
    }, 9000);
```

It's probably a good idea to go ahead and set the cache headers properly anyway, just to avoid having client browsers needlessly cache the same image over and over again.

Comment: I should have posted as an answer instead of a comment, but I wasn't sure... :)

Comment: Well I'm not a PHP programmer so I didn't (and don't) know whether PHP might put cache-prevention headers in by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 5000);
```

You probably need to call location.reload(); as well.

Comment: I think it's not working for him because he has it int he document.ready. Declaring it int he window should work for him.

Comment: I don't think that'd make any difference.

Comment: We'll see. You could be right. or I could be :-). Only the OP will know. But in any event, I think he needs to refresh the page or the changes won't show. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add query to bg.php

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
$container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php?" + n + ")");
```

the browser will not load the file with same name again

Comment: You could salt that Date() with a Math.random() to lower probability of date repetition by occasional clock adjustments ... and add 42 while you're at it :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to set the `background-image` to a different URL if you don't want to reload the entire page. However, you can attach a fragment (ex. http://example.com/index.php#fragment), or alternatively a query string (ex. http://example.com/index.php?querystring) to that URL .php file each time. If you are going to reset it every 5 seconds, a good method would be to append a [`new Date().getTime();`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) to the end of the image source URL, like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
$container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php#" + currentDate.getTime() + ")");
```

or even more succinctly/efficiently

```
$container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php#" + new Date().getTime() + ")");
```

You should end up with a `background-image` property of something like `url(bg.php#1413320228120)`. This is good because the fragment won't affect where the browser looks for the image (still `bg.php`), but it'll consider it a different URL each time and load it again.

Your solution should look something like:

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        var $container = $("header");
        $container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php)");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.css("background-image", "url(bg.php)");
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It is similar to the solution that works for me, but if use # not detected at all as unique url. Or so I think. Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoM I'm glad you found a solution. As far as the fragments, I am guessing this depends on the browser.